# Add multiple data between two weeks and display that data between that two weeks

Tags: php, jquery, charts, morris.js

I want to make a graph for the week data, the basically I collect data from patient weekly, Monday, Tuesday, wed.. ettc. So I want to display this data doctor side as weekly data.
So the graph should create like on X axis there is Week0, Week1, Week2 etc... And in between data points should display, means if Monday has 4, Tuesday has 5
{Monday:4 , Tuesday:5, Wednesday: 9 ...} so that points should display between two points Week0 and Week1 not new points on X axis.

[image]

I used below code

```
new Morris.Line({
             element: 'stifness-weeklychart',
             data: [
                    { weeksOut: 0, a: 2},
                    { weeksOut: 0, a: 2},
                    { weeksOut: 0, a: 3},
                    { weeksOut: 1, a: 3},
                    { weeksOut: 1, a: 4},
                    { weeksOut: 2, a: 4},
                    { weeksOut: 2, a: 4},
                    { weeksOut: 2, a: 3},
                    { weeksOut: 3, a: 4},
                    { weeksOut: 3, a: 6},
                    { weeksOut: 4, a: 4 },
                    { weeksOut: 4, a: 4 }],
             xkey: 'weeksOut',
             ykeys: ['a'],
             labels: ['Painlevel'],
             parseTime: false
      });
```

Comment: That is not possible with Morris. An alternative approach would be to use stacked bar charts, 1 bar per week.

Comment: Thanks, Pierre for your response, I have now found a different approach and resolve using another way.